# Resize storagesize of Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I would like to know if is make sense to resize the storageSize of MongoDB?
I recognize that my size is larger then the storage size. Maybe it decrease my performance if I retrieve data, etc..?

```
"count" : 9622,
"size" : 9329997,
"avgObjSize" : 969,
"storageSize" : 3198976,
"capped" : false
```

If is necessary how can I resize the storagesize?

Answer (score 0):

No, Per this doc [`why-are-the-files-in-my-data-directory-larger-than-the-data-in-my-database`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/storage/#why-are-the-files-in-my-data-directory-larger-than-the-data-in-my-database), it is NOT necessary to resize the storagesize. Because MongoDB preallocates data and journal files

> The data files in your data directory, which is the `/data/db` directory in default configurations, might be larger than the data set inserted into the database. Consider the following possible causes:
>
> **Preallocated data files**
>   MongoDB preallocates its data files to avoid filesystem fragmentation, and because of this, the size of these files do not necessarily reflect the size of your data.
>
> The `storage.mmapv1.smallFiles` option will reduce the size of these files, which may be useful if you have many small databases on disk.
>
> **The oplog**
>   If this mongod is a member of a replica set, the data directory includes the oplog.rs file, which is a preallocated capped collection in the local database.
>
> The default allocation is approximately 5% of disk space on 64-bit installations. In most cases, you should not need to resize the `oplog`.
>
> **The journal**
>   The data directory contains the journal files, which store write operations on disk before MongoDB applies them to databases. See Journaling.
>
> **Empty records**
>   MongoDB maintains lists of empty records in data files as it deletes documents and collections. MongoDB can reuse this space, but will not, by default, return this space to the operating system.

Also here is one good blog [how-big-is-your-mongodb](http://blog.mlab.com/2014/01/how-big-is-your-mongodb/)